# Getting error saying the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

...and a suggestion to `Use a.any() or a.all()`.

I am new to python and i am trying to implement a sabr model. I have defined a function with the following parameters:

```
def haganimpliedvol(a,f,k,B,v,t,p):
    if k != f:
        z = v/a*math.pow(f*k,(1-B)/2)*math.log(f/k)
        xz = math.log((math.sqrt(1-2*p*z+math.pow(z,2))+z-p)/(1-p))
        
        sigma = a/math.pow(f*k,(1-B)/2)*(1 + math.pow(1-B,2)/24* math.pow(math.log(f/k),2)+\
                                        math.pow(1-B,4)/1920* math.pow(math.log(f/k),4))*\
                                        xz*\
                                        (1+(math.pow(1-B,2)/24*math.pow(a,2)/math.pow(f/k,1-B)+1/4*(p*B*v*a)/math.pow(f/k,(1-B)/2)+\
                                           (2-3*math.pow(p,2))/24*math.pow(v,2)))*t
        
    else:
        sigma = a/math.pow(f,1-B)*\
        (1+(math.pow(1-B,2)/24*math.pow(a,2)/math.pow(f,(2-2*B))+\
            1/4*(p*B*a*v)/math.pow(f,1-B)+(2-3*math.pow(p,2))/24*math.pow(v,2)))*t
    
    return(sigma)
```

Now I define another function to and call the `haganimpliedvol()` function

```
params = [0.4,0.6,0.1,-0.4]

def objective(params):
    global k,sigma_iv,t,f
    a = params[0]
    B = params[1]
    v = params[2]
    p = params[1]

    for (i,j,k) in zip(k,t,f):
        calc_vols = np.array([haganimpliedvol(a,f,k,B,v,t,p)])
    return(calc_vols)
```

As can be seen, a few parameters in the functions are list. I want to get an array as an output. However, I keep getting the message in the subject line.

Comment: Please include the full stack traceback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Don't use a `if k != f:` if `k` or `f` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the variables in this call:

```
 for (i,j,k) in zip(k,t,f):
     calc_vols = np.array([haganimpliedvol(a,f,k,B,v,t,p)])
```

for the `zip` to work, `k`,`t`, `f` have to be lists or arrays of matching size;

Done use `k` for an iteration variable; it is already used in the `zip`.  I think you  are just being careless here; or confused.

And the arguments to the `hagen...` function.  Are the `f`, `k`, `t` supposed to be variables used in the `zip`?  It would make more sense to use the iteration variables (i,j,?).  Again, this just looks like you are careless, or don't care what happens.

As for the `ambiguity` error, that most likely arises in the

```
  if k != f:
```

If either `k` or `f` is an array (or both) the `k!=f` will be a boolean array.  That can't be used in `if`, which requires a simple True or False value.  It does not iterate on the conditions.  It is a basic Python `if` - a switch.

This `ambiguity` error comes up frequently, in various contexts, but all with the same basic issue - using an array in a context that requires a scalar T/F.  A simple web search should provide lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

@hpaulj thank you for leading me on the right path. I vectorized my function and made some edits and now it is working fine.

```
haganimpliedvol = np.vectorize(haganimpliedvol,excluded = ['a','B','v','p'])

params = [0.2,0.7,0.01,-0.4]

def objective(params):
    global k,sigma_iv,t,f
    a = params[0]
    B = params[1]
    v = params[2]
    p = params[1]

    calc_vols = haganimpliedvol(a,f,k,B,v,t,p)
    return(calc_vols)
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want to pass arrays into the haganimpliedvol() function?
The general convention is to write functions which take a single input type.

Maybe call it one per item in the array?

Or write the function in a way that, if it sees the input is a list it iterates and if it sees the inputs arent lists then it just calculates it one time.

See this thread for ideas
[How to make a function that can handle single inputs or lists of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011435/how-to-make-a-function-that-can-handle-single-inputs-or-lists-of-inputs)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that do not require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173).